# Serve different page to google bot crawler

Tags: indexing, seo, bots, googlebot, google-crawlers

I have an SPA with a lot of images in it. I want to expose those images to search engines. So I want to create "special" pages that will only be seen by the bot. The pages will contain metadata about the images.

Is it possible to make googlebot crawl one page but index it as another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a page which ONLY Google bot sees.

## How it works:

You basically set up a server which serves like a client's browser, and it "sits" between your "real server" which delivers the HTML and assets (JS/CSS/images) and the Crawler Bot. This server is called a *pre-render* server and it only sends data to bots, not to real clients, because it has its own URL that is mapped to use it. the URL would like like any of your pages' URLs but with some special addition at the end (probably).

The *pre-render* server acts like a browser, so the Javascript is parsed, and only when the page is ready (you would need to carefully trigger a `ready` command somewhere in your code after all the ajax has been called and you the content has "settled down", and only when that command is called, the *pre-render* server will serve the content forward to the bot, so the bot will see a "static page", "fed to it with a spoon".

[image]

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more#what-the-user-sees-what-the-crawler-sees

> In order to make your AJAX application crawlable, your site needs to
>   abide by a new agreement. This agreement rests on the following:
>
> 1. The site adopts the AJAX crawling scheme.
> 2. For each URL that has dynamically produced content, your server provides an HTML snapshot, which is the content a user (with a
>      browser) sees. Often, such URLs will be AJAX URLs, that is, URLs
>      containing a hash fragment, for example
>      www.example.com/index.html#key=value, where #key=value is the hash
>      fragment. An HTML snapshot is all the content that appears on the page
>      after the JavaScript has been executed.
> 3. The search engine indexes the HTML snapshot and serves your original AJAX URLs in search results.

---

*This technique isn't so easy to set up, but it is possible.*

Comment: Would recommend doing against that - https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html 

Quote: *If you pre-render pages, make sure that the content served to Googlebot matches the user's experience, both how it looks and how it interacts. Serving Googlebot different content than a normal user would see is considered cloaking, and would be against our Webmaster Guidelines.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to detect Google Bot via HTTP_USER_AGENT, but You will probably will get Google Ban and PR set to 0.

Comment: Do you have a link about this theme?